# How to Open the PDF file in new tab using c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, c#-4.0

Here i have problem to open the selected PDF file in new tab of browser. In below is shows the code were i done. Can anyone help me...please...

Search Button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                    string search = TextBox1.Text;
                    if (TextBox1.Text != "") 
                    {
                        string[] pdffiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.5.10\fbar\REPORT\CLOTHO\H2\REPORT\","*"+ TextBox1.Text + "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                        foreach (string file in pdffiles)
                        {
              ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file), file));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
    Response.Write("<script>alert('For this Wafer ID Report is Not Generated');</script>");
                    }
                }
```

PDF file open Button:

```
            protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    try
                    {
                    string fileName = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
                    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

                    WebClient User = new WebClient();
                    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(fileName);
                    if (FileBuffer != null)
                    {
             Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
             Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
             Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
                    }
                    }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                            {
         Response.Write("<script>alert('PDF File is not Selected');</script>");
                            }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is it a runtime issue or a compilation issue? The code you've posted won't compile due to the mis-quoted string. What errors do you get?

Comment: no error. But i need to open the pdf file in new tab..can you please help me..

Comment: This code would run on the server, and so can't directly influence the browser. You need something on the client side that opens a link with a target of _blank to open a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to inject some javascript code:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + pdf_filepath + "','_blank')</script>");
```

That should work :D

Comment: Thanks for your code.Where could i add the code. It is because i put as in below. The PDF file is cannot open in new tab. Please help me....      'code'{
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + fileName + "','_blank')</script>");
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
  Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);                  
                }

Comment: You could create a special ASPX page to display the pdf. E.g. "display_pdf.aspx".

The javascript code would open the aspx page in a new tab and append the pdf file name as a query string. E.g. 
                   display_pdf.aspx?path=csharpfordummies.pdf

The display_page.aspx will then look for the pdf file in the page_load() method, and render it using the code you have above.

'code'{ Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString()); Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer); }